# Select template based on attribute-defined order

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got the following template (excerpt):

```
<xsl:template match="section[@visible='1']">
    <dl>
        <dt><xsl:call-template name="content"/></dt>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(page|file)[@visible='1']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section[@visible=1]" mode="child" />
    </dl>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section[@visible='1']" mode="child">
    <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></dd>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is with the two `apply-template` elements at the end. The source XML elements (page, file, section,...) all have a `pos` attribute containing a number, which defines when they should be added to the output. But the way I have it currently, prevents a `section` with a lower `pos` value to be displayed before a `page` element with a higher position for example.

How can I achieve that? I've tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="section[@visible='1']">
    <dl>
        <dt><xsl:call-template name="content"/></dt>
        <xsl:call-template name="kids"/>
    </dl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="kids">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="@pos"/>
        <!-- what would go here? -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But I don't know what to put into the `for-each` loop. I could just duplicate the existing 2 templates, slap a name on them, and then call them with the current node as parameter, but that wouldn't be DRY. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<xsl:template match="section[@visible='1']">
    <dl>
        <dt><xsl:call-template name="content"/></dt>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(page|file|section)[@visible='1']" mode="m">
          <xsl:sort select="@pos"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </dl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="m">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section" mode="m">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="child"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I currently need the `mode="child"` part for the `section` template (which is a different one than the one shown). How'd you include that?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I've edited the answer to show how to handle this.

Comment: I actually had to use `<xsl:sort select="@pos" data-type="number"/>` or it would sort it `1,10,11,...` instead of `1,2,3,...`

Comment: I suspected that. The way you wrote it originally would be correct if your code was schema-aware, so I gave it the benefit of the doubt.